# difference between curent record and previous record odoo 11

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

In odoo 10, I'd like to calculate difference between a field from current record and same field from previous record
[calcul difference between 2 record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oOXe.png)

So I use this code

```py
km_parcouru = fields.Float('KM Parcouru', compute='get_km_parcouru', store=True)

@api.multi
@api.depends('odometer')
def get_km_parcouru(self):
    for record in self.sorted(lambda x:x.id):
        prev = self.env['fleet.vehicle.log.fuel'].search([], order='date desc', limit=1)
        prev_record = prev[0]['odometer'] if prev else 0
        record.km_parcouru = record.odometer - prev_record
```

Can you hellp me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a domain `[('id', '<', record.id)]` and the order `id desc` to get the previous record registered, something like this:

```py
@api.multi
@api.depends('odometer')
def get_km_parcouru(self):
    for record in self:
        prev = self.env['fleet.vehicle.log.fuel'].search([('id', '<', record.id)], order='id desc', limit=1)
        prev_record = prev[0]['odometer'] if prev else 0
        record.km_parcouru = record.odometer - prev_record
```

I hope this answer can be helpful for you.

UPDATE 15/06/2018

NewId error, its because before you save the record, record.id doesn't exist, you should override `create` and `write` method, after this methods been called `record.id` should exist. And if your compute field doesn't storage in your table maybe its because you add `store=true` after you used compute attritube, you could delete a column in your table by SQL, and restart your server.

Comment: Hi, Thnaks. I get an error in this line prev = self.env['fleet.vehicle.log.fuel'].search([('id', '<', record.id)], order='id desc', limit=1): ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'NewId'

Comment: Without domain I get the value that I want but didn't save

Comment: Thanks.  Should I override create and write in computed method?

Comment: Avoid use compute method just override create and write methods.